# Where should I store element files in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

In the plugin \qa\Plugin\Rm\View\Books I have a view \qa\Plugin\Rm\View\Books\index.ctp

I can create a element block within the same index.ctp and load it.
So I have to make the element as a stand alone ctp say header.ctp as a element.

Where should I put the header.ctp so that other view within the plugin can use?

Comment: Have you read the docs [for elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements) and [plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-views) ? Assuming you have, it's not clear where the confusion is.

Comment: I figured out "qa\Plugin\Rm\View\Elements" is the right path

Answer (score 0):

You can create in that path app/View/Elements/element.ctp and call it with this->element method (for cakephp 2).

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 2.x elements are created in following directory:

```
app/View/Elements
```

In cakephp 3.0

```
src/Template/Element
```